# Flowtype + babelify

Tags: javascript, babeljs, flowtype

I'm onto my personal project and I want to integrate flowtype. Now, within the package.json I got:

```
"babel-plugin-syntax-flow": "6.3.13"
```

which helps babelify to transcript the flowtype's syntax but it doesn't do 'flow check' and doesn't log potential errors. Should I setup a separate gulp task with a separate package for it like https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flowtype or should the the babel-plugin-syntax-flow also handle error logging?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing Babel knows about Flow is how to parse it so that it won't cause a syntax error. Generally you'd use [babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-flow-strip-types/), which enables the syntax plugin you have now, and then deletes the flow types so they don't end up in your final output. This is also enabled by default if you use the Babel preset `react`.

You'd definitely still have to use Flow's standard typechecker to do the actual static analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working solution:

You need to install:

> $ npm i --save-dev babel-plugin-syntax-flow
>   babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types babel-plugin-typecheck

Then add

```
"typecheck",
"syntax-flow",
"transform-flow-strip-types",
```

to your .babelrc configuration

Here is a sample of my configuration:

```
{
  "presets": ["stage-2", "es2015", "react"],
  "plugins": [
    "react-hot-loader/babel",
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "typecheck",
    "syntax-flow",
    "transform-flow-strip-types",
    "transform-async-to-generator"
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": ["react-hmre"]
    },
    "test":{
      "presets": ["stage-2", "es2015", "react"],
      "plugins": [
        "react-hot-loader/babel",
        "transform-decorators-legacy",
        "typecheck",
        "syntax-flow",
        "transform-flow-strip-types",
        "transform-async-to-generator"
      ],
    }
  }
}
```

This will output errors both at runtime and into your console.

Answer (score 0):

As of June 2017, all you need to do is `npm i --save-dev flow-runtime` and add:

```js
{
  "plugins": [["flow-runtime", {
    "assert": true,
    "annotate": true
  }]]
}
```